# Adding Google Analytics Segments to AWS Appflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, amazon-appflow

I am trying to add segments to my AWS Appflow that is pulling Google Analytics data.
This is because I am running into Sampling problems(Google Analytics summarizes a lot of the data and makes analysis impossible)

I can add date range filters, but even with that set the minimum, I am still in need of breaking the requests down further via segmenting. But I can not find any support articles or places online that have done similar.

I have used the Google Analytics API by itself without appflow and been able to get all the data without it sampling, but need to do something similar using appflow.

What is the correct way to add segments to a Google Analytics Appflow

Thanks in advance for any help